# NestJS Docker Postgres connection

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs

I have a problem, I can't figure out what the error is. Everything worked, the next day the server stopped connecting to the database. Created a new test project and the error is reproducible. But when I create a database with Docker and the server, everything is connected.

This gives an error, I don't understand what kind of rhombuses are

```
[Nest] 9964   - 2021-02-18 2:51:09 PM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +65ms
error: ������������ "admin" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\Programs\Test_DB_Server\test-db\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (D:\Programs\Test_DB_Server\test-db\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (D:\Programs\Test_DB_Server\test-db\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (D:\Programs\Test_DB_Server\test-db\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:10:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

so trying to connect

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      port: 5432,
      host: 'localhost',
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin',
      database: 'nestjs',
      entities: [],
    })
  ]
})
export class DatabaseModule {
}
```

docker compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_test
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - docker.env

  pgadmin:
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - docker.env
```

docker.env

```
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
POSTGRES_DB=nestjs
```

It is possible to connect to the database through the adminer, but it has not been connected through the TypeOrmModule since yesterday, and it correctly displays other errors (if the password is not correct, etc.).
Help anyone with what you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create network and bind them to same network to see each other. After that you can use "postgres" instead of localhost.

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_test
    image: postgres:latest
    networks:
      - server-net
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - docker.env

  pgadmin:
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: adminer
    networks:
      - server-net
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - docker.env
networks:
  server-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: It didn't help me, I can connect to the DB from adminer. But I can't connect with the same data from Nestjs, it gives out this incomprehensible error with diamonds. Even Google doesn't help

Comment: I was able to figure out what the problem was, I had a Postgres server, and the windows were updated at night, when I turned on the computer, the server turned on, and I started the database in docker, everything on the same port, mixed, etc. When I noticed, I turned off the server and everything worked. It's awful, I suffered with this for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of config as below.(nestJS 10.x,typeorm 10.x)

create .env file.

```
DATABASE_HOST= 
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=ashok_db
DATABASE_USER=ashok
DATABASE_PASSWORD=ashok
```

Introduce DatabaseModule ts file

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule,ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

// entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
@Module({
    imports:[
        //onfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
        ConfigModule.forRoot({envFilePath: '.env'}),
      
         TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
              imports: [ConfigModule],
               useFactory:async (configService : ConfigService)=>({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
                port: parseInt(configService.get('DATABASE_PORT')),
                username:  configService.get('DATABASE_USER'),
                password: configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
                database: configService.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
                entities: [],
                  
             inject: [ConfigService],  
         
         }),
        
    ],
})
 
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

Hope this will be work :-D